# Related product image size

Tags: magento-1.9

I have Related products in my store however they look untidy due to the size of the related image being too big. How can I change the size of the related product so it can be smaller on the frontend?
I have looked on configurations and cannot find anywhere where I can change the sizes of just the related products.

Does anyone have an idea? I have looked in other questions on this site but still I found no question related to this problem. Please can you assist me urgently.

Please see this URL: http://livecopper.co.za/multi-9-id-rccb-63a-2-pole-3ka-earth-leakage.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any module for this?

If not, I believe you should be able to edit this in catalog/product/list/related.phtml file somewhere around line 41.

quick solution:
you can add this line in styles.css like this:
.product-view .block-related .grid-indent img{width: 50%;}

or play around with:
.related-wrapper-bottom .block-related li.item .product{addWidthHere}